# Joules expansion and piston kinetic energy

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

Say I have the original Joules expansion with an ideal gas, but I don't entirely neglect the piston. It can still be considered very light, but we can't neglect its kinetic energy in the process. How could we account for this? I assume that the temperature would not stay constant anymore due to the fact that some energy is transferred to the piston as well. Can we, however, still treat the transformation as adiabatic? And how could we calculate the kinetic energy of the piston?

Comment: I don't believe the classic Joule expansion involves a piston.

Comment: If the container's and piston's walls are adiabatic, the process is still adiabatic, even if you consider the fact that there is work done in moving the piston.

Comment: Do you think that the piston is still moving in the final state?

Comment: There are certain variations of presenting the experiment where a piston is used, like https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/thermodynamic-processes-in-closed-systems/what-is-the-joule-thomson-effect/

Comment: Could you clarify your question? We calculate the kinetic energy of the piston in the normal manner as $mv^2/2$, or, alternatively, the total energy of the system (which is constant if isolated) minus the thermal energy of the gas. In other words, the gas loses energy by accelerating the piston, and that energy is returned when the piston comes to a halt. It's not clear if this is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the temperature would not stay constant anymore due to
> the fact that some energy is transferred to the piston as well.

*During* the irreversible expansion temperature gradients exist due to disequilibrium making the temperature within the chamber undefined.  But the *equilibrium* temperature of the ideal gas and piston *before and after* the expansion will be the same, since the change in internal energy is zero. That's because any work done by the gas giving the piston kinetic energy during the expansion will equal the work done on the gas by the piston bringing the piston to a stop, as must eventually occur.

This assumes the piston is totally confined within the rigid insulated chamber so that the piston does no work on the environment outside the insulated chamber. All the work done is is internal to the system. As @Chet Miller pointed out in his comment, the kinetic energy of the piston is dissipated by the viscous forces within the gas causing its motion to be damped, eventually bringing it to a stop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is important to mention that the kinetic energy of the piston is dissipated by viscous forces within the gas, which cause its motion to be damped (and ultimately to attain zero velocity).

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, that's the detail I failed to include on how the piston eventually comes to a stop. I will edit to include.  Thanks.